# Jersey WriterInterceptor: obtener cabeceras de petición

Tags: java, http, jersey

Estoy intentando escribir un objeto que implementa **WriterInterceptor** en Jersey, del lado del servidor. Para que este interceptor funcione, se necesita leer una de las cabeceras de la petición.

Les comento lo que estoy haciendo para dar contexto. Tal vez esto se pueda resolver de otra forma que por el momento no se me ha ocurrido.

1. El cliente se autentica con el servidor utilizando SRP.
2. El cliente y el servidor obtienen una **key** para poder encriptar futuros mensajes.
3. Para no registrar la **key** en base de datos, el servidor retorna (al momento de autenticarse) la cabecera **x-authentication-session-key** con un valor aleatorio.
4. El cliente debe guardar el valor de la cabecera **x-authentication-session-key** y envíarlo con cada petición que realiza. Con este valor, el servidor puede determinar la **key** generada en el paso 2 para desencriptar la petición y encriptar la respuesta.

Entonces, para desencriptar la petición y encriptar la respuesta, he decidido implementar un **interceptor**. El problema es que el interceptor que encripta la respuesta tiene que saber la **key** a utilizar y, para determinar cual es, debe conocer la cabecera de petición **x-authentication-session-key**.

El interceptor para encriptar implementa **WriterInterceptor**, pero con este no estoy encontrando la manera de obtener las cabeceras de la petición. Por el momento se me ocurrió colocar la cabecera en cada respuesta y sacarla de ahí, pero eso me obliga a colocar el código en cada endpoint.

Lo siguiente es el código reduciro del **interceptor**:

```
public class EncryptionInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

  private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_KEY_HEADER = "x-authentication-session-key";
  private final SessionManager sessionManager;

  @Inject
  public EncryptionInterceptor(final SessionManager sessionManager) {
    this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException,   WebApplicationException {

    //Obtener el valor de la cabecera aquí para determinar la **key** para encriptar los datos

    //Tengo entendido que estas son las cabeceras de la respuesta
    if (!context.getHeaders().containsKey(AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_KEY_HEADER)) {
    
      context.proceed();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

El siguiente código es el de un enpoint de ejemplo que establece la cabecera para que la pueda leer el **interceptor**:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response testCifrado(
  @Context ContainerRequestContext requestContext
  ) {
  String headerName = "x-authentication-session-key";
  String header = requestContext.getHeaderString(headerName);

  return Response
    .ok(new Object() {
      public String getLala() {
        return "lalala";
      }
    })
    .header(headerName, header)
    .build();
}
```

Mi idea es no tener que establecer la cabecera en el endpoint, ni siquiera debería interesar en ese lugar que la cabecera se encuentre en la petición. Tengo la idea de que el endpoint quede de la siguiente manera:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/json")
public Object testCifrado() {

  return new Object() {
      public String getLala() {
        return "lalala";
      }
  };
}
```

¿Cómo puedo leer desde **un WriterInterceptor** las cabeceras de la petición?

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

> EDIT 1

Por el momento pude solucionar la parte de establecer la cabecera en el endpoint. Colocando un **Filter**, establezco en la respuesta la cabecera que viene desde la petición.

```
public class EncryptionFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(
  ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
  ContainerResponseContext responseContext
) {

  if (!requestContext.getHeaders().containsKey("x-authentication-session-key")) {
    return;
  }

  responseContext.getHeaders().add(
    "x-authentication-session-key",
    requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("x-authentication-session-key")
  );
}
```

}

No lo veo como una solución elegante, pero por el momento sirve. Creo que mejor sería poder acceder a las cabeceras de la petición desde el **WriterInterceptor**.